# How to build a project (say zeromq) as static library and linked it into my project

Tags: linux, build, hyperlink, zeromq

I want to use the zeroMQ in my project
and I run the configure as below to build the libaray into my home folder

```
./configure --enable-static --disable-shared --prefix=/home/xx/out
```

then I link my project by

```
gcc -o myproject x.c y.c /home/xx/out/libzmq.a
```

but there still a lot of link error like below:

```
../zmq/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-ip.o): In function zmq::resolve_ip_interface(sockaddr_storage*, unsigned int*, char const*)':
/home/sureone/share/zeromq-2.2.0/src/ip.cpp:221: undefined reference to std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()'
/home/sureone/share/zeromq-2.2.0/src/ip.cpp:222: undefined reference to std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()'
../zmq/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-ip.o): In function zmq::resolve_ip_hostname(sockaddr_storage*, unsigned int*, char const*)':
/home/sureone/share/zeromq-2.2.0/src/ip.cpp:314: undefined reference to std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, uns
```

...........

Comment: You realize that ØMQ is LGPL, right?

Comment: LGPL with a static linking exception http://www.zeromq.org/area:licensing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> gcc -o myproject x.c y.c /home/xx/out/libzmq.a

Since ZeroMQ is (apparently) using C++, you need to use appropriate compiler driver (`g++` in this case) to link it.

Try this:

```
 gcc -c x.c y.c
 g++ -o myproject x.o y.o /home/xx/out/libzmq.a
```

Comment: I have resolved this problem , should put -lstdc++ after all the object file and libzmq.a not before them.

Comment: @sureone "should put -lstdc++ after all the object" -- while this solution appears to work, it is not necessarily correct, and may not work tomorrow. You *really* ought to use `g++` when linking C++ code.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I tried as your way, it do resolved my issue.

Comment: I think you have statically compiled the zeroMQ library, but finally linked it dynamically. You should add `-static` to that link step in this answer. I will submit an edit.

Comment: @SubinSebastian You are mistaken: `-static` is neither necessary, nor desirable here.

Comment: Isn't that OP's question? I see s/he want to statically link zeroMQ

Comment: @SubinSebastian The OP question is how to link against archive version of ZeroMQ and this answer (_without_ `-static`) achieves _exactly_ that. Added `-static` achieves something _else_. If you don't understand the difference, you can ask a question about that.