# zeromq-4.1.3 runs program error in Ubuntu14.04

Tags: zeromq

I'm new in zeromq. After install zeromq-4.1.3, I just run the "Hello World" example in C from "http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all" in the following way:

1. `gcc -c hwclient.c`
2. `g++ -o client hwclient.o -lzmq`

But it appears many "undefined reference to": (I'm sorry that I don't have enough rep to upload a screenshot)

> //usr/local/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-pipe.o): In function `zmq::mutex_t::try_lock()':
>   /usr/software/zeromq-4.1.3/src/mutex.hpp:114: undefined reference to`pthread_mutex_trylock'
>   //usr/local/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-ctx.o): In function `zmq::ctx_t::~ctx_t()':
>   /usr/software/zeromq-4.1.3/src/ctx.cpp:117: undefined reference to`randombytes_close'
>   //usr/local/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-thread.o): In function `thread_routine':
>   /usr/software/zeromq-4.1.3/src/thread.cpp:91: undefined reference to`pthread_sigmask'
>   //usr/local/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-thread.o): In function `zmq::thread_t::start(void (*)(void*), void*)':
>   /usr/software/zeromq-4.1.3/src/thread.cpp:105: undefined reference to`pthread_create'
>   //usr/local/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-thread.o): In function `zmq::thread_t::stop()':
>   /usr/software/zeromq-4.1.3/src/thread.cpp:111: undefined reference to`pthread_join'
>   //usr/local/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-zmq_utils.o): In function `zmq_curve_keypair':
>   /usr/software/zeromq-4.1.3/src/zmq_utils.cpp:202: undefined reference to`crypto_box_keypair'
>   //usr/local/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-curve_client.o): In function `zmq::curve_client_t::encode(zmq::msg_t*)':
>   /usr/software/zeromq-4.1.3/src/curve_client.cpp:151: undefined reference to`crypto_box_afternm'
>   //usr/local/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-curve_client.o): In function `zmq::curve_client_t::decode(zmq::msg_t*)':
>   /usr/software/zeromq-4.1.3/src/curve_client.cpp:214: undefined reference to`crypto_box_open_afternm'
>   //usr/local/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-curve_client.o): In function `zmq::curve_client_t::curve_client_t(zmq::options_t const&)':
>   /usr/software/zeromq-4.1.3/src/curve_client.cpp:61: undefined reference to`sodium_init'
>   /usr/software/zeromq-4.1.3/src/curve_client.cpp:65: undefined reference to `crypto_box_keypair'
>   //usr/local/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-curve_client.o): In function`zmq::curve_client_t::produce_hello(zmq::msg_t*)':
>   /usr/software/zeromq-4.1.3/src/curve_client.cpp:265: undefined reference to `crypto_box'
>   //usr/local/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-curve_client.o): In function`zmq::curve_client_t::process_welcome(unsigned char const*, unsigned long)':
>   /usr/software/zeromq-4.1.3/src/curve_client.cpp:310: undefined reference to `crypto_box_open'
>   /usr/software/zeromq-4.1.3/src/curve_client.cpp:320: undefined reference to`crypto_box_beforenm'
>   //usr/local/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-curve_client.o): In function `zmq::curve_client_t::produce_initiate(zmq::msg_t*)':
>   /usr/software/zeromq-4.1.3/src/curve_client.cpp:340: undefined reference to`randombytes'
>   /usr/software/zeromq-4.1.3/src/curve_client.cpp:344: undefined reference to `crypto_box'
>   /usr/software/zeromq-4.1.3/src/curve_client.cpp:380: undefined reference to`crypto_box'
>   //usr/local/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-curve_client.o): In function `zmq::curve_client_t::process_ready(unsigned char const*, unsigned long)':
>   /usr/software/zeromq-4.1.3/src/curve_client.cpp:424: undefined reference to`crypto_box_open_afternm'
>   //usr/local/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-curve_server.o): In function `zmq::curve_server_t::encode(zmq::msg_t*)':
>   /usr/software/zeromq-4.1.3/src/curve_server.cpp:157: undefined reference to`crypto_box_afternm'
>   //usr/local/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-curve_server.o): In function `zmq::curve_server_t::decode(zmq::msg_t*)':
>   /usr/software/zeromq-4.1.3/src/curve_server.cpp:223: undefined reference to`crypto_box_open_afternm'
>   //usr/local/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-curve_server.o): In function `zmq::curve_server_t::curve_server_t(zmq::session_base_t*, std::string const&, zmq::options_t const&)':
>   /usr/software/zeromq-4.1.3/src/curve_server.cpp:64: undefined reference to`sodium_init'
>   /usr/software/zeromq-4.1.3/src/curve_server.cpp:68: undefined reference to `crypto_box_keypair'
>   //usr/local/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-curve_server.o): In function`zmq::curve_server_t::process_hello(zmq::msg_t*)':
>   /usr/software/zeromq-4.1.3/src/curve_server.cpp:319: undefined reference to `crypto_box_open'
>   //usr/local/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-curve_server.o): In function`zmq::curve_server_t::produce_welcome(zmq::msg_t*)':
>   /usr/software/zeromq-4.1.3/src/curve_server.cpp:340: undefined reference to `randombytes'
>   /usr/software/zeromq-4.1.3/src/curve_server.cpp:350: undefined reference to`randombytes'
>   /usr/software/zeromq-4.1.3/src/curve_server.cpp:355: undefined reference to `crypto_secretbox'
>   /usr/software/zeromq-4.1.3/src/curve_server.cpp:365: undefined reference to`randombytes'
>   /usr/software/zeromq-4.1.3/src/curve_server.cpp:377: undefined reference to `crypto_box'
>   //usr/local/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-curve_server.o): In function`zmq::curve_server_t::produce_ready(zmq::msg_t*)':
>   /usr/software/zeromq-4.1.3/src/curve_server.cpp:547: undefined reference to `crypto_box_afternm'
>   //usr/local/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-curve_server.o): In function`zmq::curve_server_t::process_initiate(zmq::msg_t*)':
>   /usr/software/zeromq-4.1.3/src/curve_server.cpp:421: undefined reference to `crypto_secretbox_open'
>   /usr/software/zeromq-4.1.3/src/curve_server.cpp:454: undefined reference to`crypto_box_open'
>   /usr/software/zeromq-4.1.3/src/curve_server.cpp:479: undefined reference to `crypto_box_open'
>   /usr/software/zeromq-4.1.3/src/curve_server.cpp:496: undefined reference to`crypto_box_beforenm'
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I also use the method in "[How to build a project (say zeromq) as static library and linked it into my project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10273608/how-to-build-a-project-say-zeromq-as-static-library-and-linked-it-into-my-proj)":

```
./configure --enable-static --disable-shared --prefix=/home/gsp/zeromqworkspace/test

g++ -o client hwclient.o /home/gsp/zeromqworkspace/test/libzmq.a
```

It turns out to be: "g++: error: /home/gsp/zeromqworkspace/test/libzmq.a: No such file or directory".

I don't know what to do. I looking forward to your answers. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The `pthread` functions should be linked in by adding the `-lpthread` switch to the `g++` statement.

If the new linker switch gives an error that the library is not found, try `sudo apt-get install libpthread-stubs0-dev`

Comment: Did it decreased number of error logs? I think you might be also missing libsodium library.

Comment: You don;t need to user pthread symbols, the ZMQ library will. Are you still getting errors on the unresolved libpthread references? Or is it just the randombytes etc (libsodium)?

Comment: I write the result in the following answer since it's too long.

Answer (score 0):

When I run: g++ -o client zmqclient.o -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lzmq -lpthread, the result changes to the following:

gsp@gsp-Lenovo:~/zeromqworkspace/test$ g++ -o client zmqclient.o -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lzmq -lpthread
/usr/local/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-ctx.o): In function `zmq::ctx_t::~ctx_t()':
/usr/software/zeromq-4.1.3/src/ctx.cpp:117: undefined reference to`randombytes_close'
/usr/local/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-zmq_utils.o): In function `zmq_curve_keypair':
/usr/software/zeromq-4.1.3/src/zmq_utils.cpp:202: undefined reference to`crypto_box_keypair'
/usr/local/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-curve_client.o): In function `zmq::curve_client_t::encode(zmq::msg_t*)':
/usr/software/zeromq-4.1.3/src/curve_client.cpp:151: undefined reference to`crypto_box_afternm'
/usr/local/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-curve_client.o): In function `zmq::curve_client_t::decode(zmq::msg_t*)':
/usr/software/zeromq-4.1.3/src/curve_client.cpp:214: undefined reference to`crypto_box_open_afternm'
/usr/local/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-curve_client.o): In function `zmq::curve_client_t::curve_client_t(zmq::options_t const&)':
/usr/software/zeromq-4.1.3/src/curve_client.cpp:61: undefined reference to`sodium_init'
/usr/software/zeromq-4.1.3/src/curve_client.cpp:65: undefined reference to `crypto_box_keypair'
/usr/local/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-curve_client.o): In function`zmq::curve_client_t::produce_hello(zmq::msg_t*)':
/usr/software/zeromq-4.1.3/src/curve_client.cpp:265: undefined reference to `crypto_box'
/usr/local/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-curve_client.o): In function`zmq::curve_client_t::process_welcome(unsigned char const*, unsigned long)':
/usr/software/zeromq-4.1.3/src/curve_client.cpp:310: undefined reference to `crypto_box_open'
/usr/software/zeromq-4.1.3/src/curve_client.cpp:320: undefined reference to`crypto_box_beforenm'
/usr/local/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-curve_client.o): In function `zmq::curve_client_t::produce_initiate(zmq::msg_t*)':
/usr/software/zeromq-4.1.3/src/curve_client.cpp:340: undefined reference to`randombytes'
/usr/software/zeromq-4.1.3/src/curve_client.cpp:344: undefined reference to `crypto_box'
/usr/software/zeromq-4.1.3/src/curve_client.cpp:380: undefined reference to`crypto_box'
/usr/local/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-curve_client.o): In function `zmq::curve_client_t::process_ready(unsigned char const*, unsigned long)':
/usr/software/zeromq-4.1.3/src/curve_client.cpp:424: undefined reference to`crypto_box_open_afternm'
/usr/local/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-curve_server.o): In function `zmq::curve_server_t::encode(zmq::msg_t*)':
/usr/software/zeromq-4.1.3/src/curve_server.cpp:157: undefined reference to`crypto_box_afternm'
/usr/local/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-curve_server.o): In function `zmq::curve_server_t::decode(zmq::msg_t*)':
/usr/software/zeromq-4.1.3/src/curve_server.cpp:223: undefined reference to`crypto_box_open_afternm'
/usr/local/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-curve_server.o): In function `zmq::curve_server_t::curve_server_t(zmq::session_base_t*, std::string const&, zmq::options_t const&)':
/usr/software/zeromq-4.1.3/src/curve_server.cpp:64: undefined reference to`sodium_init'
/usr/software/zeromq-4.1.3/src/curve_server.cpp:68: undefined reference to `crypto_box_keypair'
/usr/local/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-curve_server.o): In function`zmq::curve_server_t::process_hello(zmq::msg_t*)':
/usr/software/zeromq-4.1.3/src/curve_server.cpp:319: undefined reference to `crypto_box_open'
/usr/local/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-curve_server.o): In function`zmq::curve_server_t::produce_welcome(zmq::msg_t*)':
/usr/software/zeromq-4.1.3/src/curve_server.cpp:340: undefined reference to `randombytes'
/usr/software/zeromq-4.1.3/src/curve_server.cpp:350: undefined reference to`randombytes'
/usr/software/zeromq-4.1.3/src/curve_server.cpp:355: undefined reference to `crypto_secretbox'
/usr/software/zeromq-4.1.3/src/curve_server.cpp:365: undefined reference to`randombytes'
/usr/software/zeromq-4.1.3/src/curve_server.cpp:377: undefined reference to `crypto_box'
/usr/local/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-curve_server.o): In function`zmq::curve_server_t::produce_ready(zmq::msg_t*)':
/usr/software/zeromq-4.1.3/src/curve_server.cpp:547: undefined reference to `crypto_box_afternm'
/usr/local/lib/libzmq.a(libzmq_la-curve_server.o): In function`zmq::curve_server_t::process_initiate(zmq::msg_t*)':
/usr/software/zeromq-4.1.3/src/curve_server.cpp:421: undefined reference to `crypto_secretbox_open'
/usr/software/zeromq-4.1.3/src/curve_server.cpp:454: undefined reference to`crypto_box_open'
/usr/software/zeromq-4.1.3/src/curve_server.cpp:479: undefined reference to `crypto_box_open'
/usr/software/zeromq-4.1.3/src/curve_server.cpp:496: undefined reference to`crypto_box_beforenm'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: I think you are missing (libsodium) library. However I don't know how did you manage to install ZMQ in the first place.

Comment: I install ZMQ in the following way: firstly "sudo apt-get install libtool autoconf automake", then " tar -zxvf libsodium-1.0.3.tar.gz
 cd libsodium-1.0.3
 sudo ./autogen.sh
 sudo ./configure && make check
 sudo make install
 sudo ldconfig
 cd .." and next "tar -zxvf zeromq-x.x.x.tar.gz
　　cd zeromq-2.1.7
　　./configure
　　make
　　sudo make install"

Answer (score 0):

The `undefined reference to` messages mean that one or more libraries are missing.

Based on all the references to cryptographic operations, it looks like `lib sodium` and maybe also `pthread` are missing.  To confirm this, you could try adding a direct library reference to `lib sodium` with

```
-l/usr/local/lib/libsodium.a
```

and maybe also

```
-lpthread
```

of course change the path to wherever

```
libsodium.a
```

is actually installed.

Answer (score 0):

Remember to use the library in the program you are compiling with gcc etc.:

```
-lzmq -lsodioum
```

or "remember to add your extra flags ex. -g -O2 -w"

```
./configure TYPEFLAGS='-lzmq -lsodium'
```

if configure sets the settings, do only ./configure above;

```
make TYPEFLAGS='-lzmq -lsodium'
```

Where TYPEFLAGS can be CFLAGS, CXXFLAGS, LDFLAGS and so on.